# Adding aria attributes to details elements

Tags: html, accessibility

When using the `<details>` and `<summary>` elements, do you need to add any aria attributes for accessibility? Or, put another way, would adding any aria attributes enhance the element's accessibility in some way? I'm thinking `aria-expanded`, `aria-pressed`, `aria-role`, etc.

I know details is a semantic element, but I'm wondering if there's any real benefit to adding them, or if they're at best redundant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a few cases where the tag does not have the expected information, such as using a checkbox to force CSS states then there is a requirement to use the aria-labelledby attribute in particular to pass AA success criterion.

This falls under WCAG 2.1 Chapter 3.1.2 - [Language of Parts](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/#language-of-parts)

There is an interesting Wiki about [Using ARIA to Provide for Hidden Labels](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-label_to_provide_an_invisible_label)

If you do have the expected information in your details or summary then the screen reader will gain no benefit from reading that info twice.

Comment: This **does not** fall under WCAG 2.1 Chapter 3.1.2 - Language of parts.

Comment: Thank you so much for your opinion Adam.

Comment: You're welcome. That was probably a mistake of yours, but you should edit your post because it could be very misleading as this question has nothing to do with languages.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the ARIA in HTML specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#details), the  `details` element has an implicit role of `group`

The `group` role is defined as "Name from author" [in ARIA specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#group) so it does require a `summary` element OR an `aria-label` attribute OR an `aria-labelledby` attribute.

```
<!-- simple use case with a summary -->
<details>
    <summary>View more details</summary>
    ...
</details>

<!-- This can be used with an empty summary if you just want the icon visually -->
<details aria-label="Details">
    <summary></summary>
    ...
</details>

<!-- or you can reference another element(s) -->
<div class="display: none" id="detailsfor">Details for</div>
<div id="myproduct">My product</div>
<details aria-describedby="detailsfor myproduct">
   ...
</details>
```

As long as you are using the native HTML elements (`details` and `summary`) you do not want to wonder about adding any other ARIA attribute